# How To Change textbox TextMode using a CheckBox?

Tags: c#

Changing textmode doesnt work despite it go to the server and debug
Here is the design

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="Show Password" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is the code

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;


        }
        else
        {
            txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `doesnt work` what does it mean?

Comment: It will go to to server as you are having autopostback=true, and what is not working?

Comment: the textmode of the password doesnt changed to singleLine